# What is the name of the CentOS font?

Tags: linux, fonts, centos

What is the name of the font used in the CentOS logo?

[Link to CentOS Site](http://www.centos.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be something around Handel Gothic Bold or just the Handel family of fonts.

Used: http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/